# Frama-c fails to prove fact about pointer comparison

Tags: frama-c

Consider the following C code:

```
#include <assert.h>

//@ requires p < q;
void f(char *p, char *q)
{
    assert(p <= q-1);
}

//@ requires a < b;
void g(int a, int b)
{
    assert(a <= b-1);
}
```

Using alt-ergo, frama-c successfully proves that the assertion in `g()` holds but fail to prove the same with `f()`. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formally, pointers and integers are two very different things. In particular, C semantics states that pointer comparison is well defined only for pointers that points in the same allocated block (or one offset past the end of said allocated block) . This is reflected in the model used by the WP plugin of Frama-C in the definition of `addr_le` and friends (see `$(frama-c -print-share-path)/wp/why3/Memory.why`), where the pointers are checked to have the same address before the comparison is done on their offset.